# Zabbix upgraded from 4.2 to 5.2 after that we are not able to fetch data from agent

Tags: upgrade, zabbix

Zabbix upgraded from 4.2 to 5.2 after that we are not able to fetch data from the newly configured agent.

Whereas I can see the agent ZBX icon is green on the Zabbix server. ..

Agent log shows....

27399:20210715:172042.328 failed to accept an incoming connection: connection from "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" rejected, allowed hosts: "zabbixpoc.example.net"
27399:20210715:172142.147 failed to accept an incoming connection: connection from "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" rejected, allowed hosts: "zabbixpoc.example.net"

As such Zabbix server and agent running on the same server. I checked Telnet is working. But in the latest data, no data coming. If we try fetching data via zabbix_get, we are getting data on cli.

Zabbix server 5.2
Agent 4.2.1

any help!!!

Comment: Hi... Can someone help here

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this when the agent was configured to use localhost (127.0.0.1) for the Server= and ServerActive= configuration. Change that to the public IP address, the one the Zabbix server is listening on, in the zabbix_agentd.conf file.